# Can I use cmocka to mock a function that returns a struct?

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

I have a simple structure with two data members.

```
typedef struct
{
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
} MyStructType;
```

And I have a function that returns the struct by value.

```
MyStructType get_my_struct(void)
{
    MyStructType test = { 1, 2 };
    return test;
}
```

So, how can I mock `get_my_struct()` using cmocka?

I tried

```
MyStructType get_my_struct(void)
{
    return mock_type(MyStructType);
}

// or

MyStructType get_my_struct(void)
{
    return mock_ptr_type(MyStructType*);
}
```

but I get compile errors.

I read [the cmocka documentation for mock objects](https://api.cmocka.org/group__cmocka__mock.html), but it didn't give me a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can dereference a mocked pointer type,

```
MyStruct get_my_struct(void)
{
    return *mock_ptr_type(MyStructType*);
}
```

but you need to make sure will_return() is not `NULL`.